# Calculate union type of key names in object whose values are indexable

Tags: typescript

I would like to write an `indexByProp` function which limits the selection of props to index by to those which are indexable values (strings, numbers, symbols).

This issue is a continuation of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33521. My attempt so far to build this function can be found in this [TS Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwIYCMA2EA8AVKAXigFc4BrOAewHc4A+IqAJQgGMqAnBHAZ2E4BLOAHMoAHyhwSAW3QROAGih56AKDWhIsRCgzYA0hBC8cAeSgpgERLx1I0WCI0JqoUMwG1yxqgDMPAF1LZGtbKH4hUQkpWXlOGN4QOSpMKDd3KAB+KAAiLIKs3KgAehKoHABaSqkICAQ7YCooTgg-BSgmzoALaARBSMF0EmsEKBkIOQU7fygAAx8QWbM5jPcALlqANwUNDjh+KGEHACEQAAVOKjAmHAANELCG+z0negAKDLArsAA5VAmm3gDn0ECMJnu9EUGWQvE2d08gWhAEogbpHNhIURGABvDL7Q68OoINEgpxY4g4gC+GVawBInDgUFhADpWggSGwIO93scUMpkMjsVA8ZkoATgFBUAgEK1eHZiMhPN9rv8JoE1kd0Z5pbKIPLgorNXSGUy+cgMlTlET6si1DS1GVOvrgBpzWdLtd3gBydCoTje5SeHGlcq8bpUEiYMbyKBUcgZP2cTYARmUGT8VCom29ACZA+l3ABHEjITbvIWEXE0qmBO1qd0XH4+kvIAvB0MRCNRmPQLTQBRXTiJ-2p9PuTPZqB5gsZVvlyvV+11oA).

The desired outcome I expect is, for example:

```
indexByProp('bar', [{ // should be ok
  bar: 1, 
  foo: '2', 
  qux: () => {}
}])

indexByProp('qux', [{ // should be type error
  bar: 1, 
  foo: '2', 
  qux: () => {}
}])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = NonNullable<
  { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
>;
```

where `KeysMatching<T, V>` gives you the keys of `T` whose properties are assignable to `V`.  It [looks up](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#keyof-and-lookup-types) the property values of a [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types), [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) type to do this.  An example to show how it works:

```
interface Foo {
  a?: string;
  b: number;
}

// give me all the keys of Foo whose properties are assignable to 
// string | undefined... expect to get "a" back
type Example = KeysMatching<Foo, string | undefined>;
```

This is evaluated like this:

```
type Example2 = NonNullable<
  {
    a?: Foo["a"] extends string | undefined ? "a" : never;
    b: Foo["b"] extends string | undefined ? "b" : never;
  }["a" | "b"]
>;

type Example3 = NonNullable<
  {
    a?: string | undefined extends string | undefined ? "a" : never;
    b: number extends string ? "b" : never;
  }["a" | "b"]
>;

type Example4 = NonNullable<{ a?: "a"; b: never }["a" | "b"]>;

type Example5 = NonNullable<"a" | undefined | never>;

type Example6 = NonNullable<"a" | undefined>;

type Example7 = "a";
```

Which gives `"a"` as expected.

---

Then, `IndexableKeys` is just:

```
type IndexableKeys<T> = KeysMatching<T, keyof any>;
```

and your `indexByProp()` function looks like:

```
const indexByProp = <X extends Indexable>(
  propName: IndexableKeys<X>,
  xs: X[]
): Indexable<X> => {
  const seed: Indexable<X> = {};
  return xs.reduce((index, x) => {
    const address = x[propName];
    index[address as keyof typeof index] = x; // need assertion
    return index;
  }, seed);
};
```

And your tests behave as desired:

```
indexByProp("bar", [
  {
    bar: 1,
    foo: "2",
    qux: () => {}
  }
]); // okay

indexByProp("qux", [
  //        ~~~~~  error!
  // Argument of type '"qux"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"bar" | "foo"'.
  {
    // should be type error
    bar: 1,
    foo: "2",
    qux: () => {}
  }
]);
```

Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwIYCMA2EA8AVKAXigFc4BrOAewHc4A+IqAJQgGMqAnBHAZ2E4BLOAHMoAHyhwSAW3QROAGih56AbgBQG0JCgBpCCF4BZVMDYALYSPzKAao2IA5KnCclMmDNhwaoUAG8oAG09KGEockMqADMVAF0ALhVQ+KgUYAhEXig7KAB+fShkuAgANwUoAF9gqJBYhI11LR1oeCQ0LAgDI3xHfUMTM0trW0jouNQ4EGaNDjh+cMQUACEQAAVOKjAmHAANdORM7Nhlzux6AAo-KDAtsCdUGQhk9pRvbsH9+kUb5F5kntgvENABKV5nD7fIiMAI3eaLXgQCAICEdKF7foBKqafycCDAEicOBQf4AOnxCBIbAgl0uwg6ymQoJhgRu-gRwCgqAQCHxvByxGQwTu20ez3iuP8Sw6wR5fIgAu5OTqDVaDQZKDSQrUUAA9HqpMiEMqkZxgIJXOyoPjCcSZSgpVVlEiUaDNDitJrkGtNttLgAidCoTgB5TBG5w6VQYOcZIARl+0ZiVCoyQDACYw9aAI4kZDJS4swiwqo3Mvxd36w1UcioEBes6++6BvPIMMhG4G6PRgB+-f7-gUW04AEIu4aAIKcESyLJctXgaAAcgDbYDy-COWoXNQAsEIjgHygwCotxDTwJlUXulXsYDEigAZTVA3ZMj1u7vAsVA8JvkJ5LuknAjtasYJkm0ovumWaQf4baFsWpblholaaBoBqYVh2E4d2ACieyTsY6wADJ4Y2mScDEqA0lAABiqZsv4qD5Mk-BCKIUroCUsjyJwHpaN2IiCBUUDPNyngnhY0B1DkDQMWeNA-kitz3AoFqKty+KmgeR5dCeVAYYa7HWI+ZBIDEwgomSNmHJAbBcqeUAiAST6oA+wZsOQ2hAXhaAyGA2BMD0QzmFYog4ApLoCKZkjmRAlmlAgsytFAflPIFEAZkwLhuB4XhdL4-hRtKLHJApwQBu5aQZFkCA5CZohmcsiUogUbkPiU5QKFK-jcfRqaVegAY1UcdUNTFTVxS1VkmoUQadUaFT8eWlXuY+C0gilvn+ZlADMOWuO4nhQh+0ZlVAjViNNFmzYcxz1Zdk3XaQM1Je1VWLaUy29TGPFyJUtUnFdH3DcUS09atn0bcNW3oal6UBdgAAsh15SdhVBBdn26v132VDU0OSJt226IjmUAKxo8dBU+ETr23e9kj45wpPQOT2AAGzU-lUL0-FrXJfDO0ZdgADsTA4xoQA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz this is a really helpful answer. Helped me see the bigger picture of how the various features are coming together.